# ReactJS - setState() is not updating

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a single page create-react-app project and the issue I am having is that the state is not updating. I have cut some of my code out just to make the example a bit shorter and easier to follow. The function where setState() is called is in form_change().

My goal here is to change the color of the text when there is an error, but even {this.state.test} isn't updating. I have tried putting console.log()s in various locations to get around the async nature of setState, but unfortunately they seem to show that state is never updated. It has been a while since I have used React, so there is a chance I am doing something very silly!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'; 
import './App.css';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown'
import classes from './classes.module.css'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css';
const axios = require('axios');

class App extends Component {
  render(){

  const error_empty = (param)=>{
    if (this.state.error===undefined){
      return false
    }
    else{
      
      if (this.state.errors.find(el => el === param) === undefined){
        return false
      }
      else return true


    }
  }

  const form_change = (event, param)=>{
    
    let form={...this.state.form};
    form[param]=event.target.value;

    let errors =verified(form);
  
  console.log(form); //as expected
  console.log(errors); //as expected
 
 //works up til here. setState not updating for some reason.
 this.setState({form:form,errors:errors,test:'Hello World'})


    
    
  }
const verified = (data)=>{
  let errors = [];
  let form = data;

errors.push('ean')
return errors}

  this.state = {
    example:['abc'],
    form:{
      example:"abc"
    }
  }


  return (

    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className={classes.button_holder}>
        <div className={classes.page_button} onClick={()=>{null}}>
              {this.state.test}
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.user_form}>User Update Form
        <div>
        <input className={classes.input_text} style={{color: error_empty()?'red':'black'}} value={this.state.form.ean} onChange={(event)=>{form_change(event,'ean')}} placeholder={"EAN"}></input>
        </div>
          </div>
    
      
      </header>

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you will find the answer of your question here; but head up to reactjs.org and learn more of the fundamentals of react components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move initialization of state outside render function `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialise your state in constructor
2. Don't update your state (this.setState) in render because this will lead to infinitive loop.
3. Move your functions error_empty(), form_change() and verified() outside the render.
4. To call function onChange use `this`

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      example:['abc'],
      form:{
        example:"abc"
      }
      error: ""
    }
  }

  error_empty = (param) => {
    if(this.state.error===undefined) {
      return false
    }
    else {
      if(this.state.errors.find(el => el === param) === undefined) {
        return false  
       }
      return true
    }
   }

  ...
    
      render() {
        ...
        <input ... onChange={(event) => {this.form_change(event,'ean')}}/>
        ...
      }
    }
```